# not able see messages published from Kafka producer(Spring Integration)

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Im using Spring Integration in Java Rest api to produce messages into Kafka..
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka

when i say

```
kafkaMessageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("hi kafka from rest api").build());
```

this returns **true** that means its publishing ..but not able to see the messages in the topic logs..
i checked the logs under /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs/test-0

even i ran the consumer console but im not able to see the messages published from api..

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

but if i produce messages from producer console im able to see messages in the topic logs as well as consumer console..

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

im using same brokerlist and topic name in spring integrated rest api..

my spring config outbound xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <int:channel id="producerKafka">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
            id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
            kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
            channel="producerKafka">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5" keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500"/>

    <int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="localhost:9092"
                                          topic="test"                                     
                                          sync="true"
                                          key-class-type="java.lang.String" 
                                          key-encoder="encoder"
                                          value-class-type="java.lang.String" 
                                          value-encoder="encoder"
                                          partitioner="partitioner"                                             
                                          compression-type="none"
                                          producer-listener="kafkalistner"/>
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>

    <bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringEncoder" />
<bean id="kafkalistner" class="kafka.producer.rest.model.ProducerListnerKafka" />
    <bean id="partitioner" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.DefaultPartitioner"/>


</beans>
```

And the listener implementation..

```
 public class ProducerListnerKafka extends LoggingProducerListener{

        @Override
        public void setIncludeContents(boolean includeContents) {
            super.setIncludeContents(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String topic, Integer partition, Object key, Object payload, Exception exception) {
            super.onError(topic, partition, key, payload, exception);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String topic, Integer partition, Object key, Object value, RecordMetadata recordMetadata) {
        String kafkatopic=recordMetadata.topic();

        }


    }
```

i tried debugging its not even coming to onError function.

Comment: Can you post a little bit more about your Spring integration configuration?

Comment: updated question with outbound channel xml..its similar to the one mentioend in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka

Comment: Try with `sync="true"` and take a look into logs if there is some StackTrace on the matter.

Comment: @ArtemBilan i made this change sync="true" ..i didnt see the message in the topic log under /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs/test-0 ...it has messges published from producer console but not messages from api...and there is no stacktrace in the logs..it has only the messages

Comment: i have downloaded Kafka tool kafkatool.com/download.html to see the messages even there it shows only messages published from kafka producer console...not message from api

Comment: No, I mean your application logs! Of course, not Kafka. Since there is no messages delivered to the Kafka, we have some issue on your application level.

Comment: @ArtemBilan there is no error in my application log...even the send method is returning true..it means the message is sent to kafka right??? correct me if im wrong..

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Can you confirm that you have it with the `sync="true"`? How about to try with the `producer-listener`, e.g. `LoggingProducerListener` ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have already tried with sync="true" ...but not sure about producer-listener ...please suggest some sample..

Comment: ??? Since version `1.3` the `<int-kafka:producer-configuration>` supports the `producer-listener` as a bean reference. See its JavaDocs

Comment: @ArtemBilan sorry im very new to kafka im referring to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka   please point to right repo for referring producer-listener

Comment: That's correct repo. Not sure why you think that you should go somewhere else. I just point you that you should declare `<bean>` for the `org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ProducerListener` implementation and use its `id` from the `producer-listener` attribute on your `<int-kafka:producer-configuration>`. Nothing more. If that is still not clear for you, I'd advice to go th the Core Spring Framework documentation or some book on the matter.

Comment: sorry i didnt realize that it is an attribute in xsd definition https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/1.3.x/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/kafka/config/spring-integration-kafka-1.3.xsd

Comment: @ArtemBilan updated question after trying your suggestion..please check

Comment: Wow! You can debug that! Why then don't go into the `ProducerConfiguration.send()` and see what's going on with your message to send?

Comment: @ArtemBilan When you say ProducerConfiguration.send() im assuming its  kafkaMessageChannel.send()..but i cannot go inside this method while debugging as its just an interface..and would like to know how adding listener made difference now..correct me if im wrong..still the send method is returning true..which means message sent to kafka..

Comment: ??? `ProducerConfiguration` is a class from Spring Integration Kafka and if you use some dependency management tool, you can step in to its source code with during debug. Or you can do the same with the `ProducerListener.onSuccess()` implementation if that is difficult for you to debug the Framework code. With the `ProducerListener` I try to collect some clues what's wrong with your environment. If that didn't work, you wouldn't be an along with the issue. Something wrong somewhere else not in the adapter. Maybe you send messages into the wrong message channel, not into that `producerKafka`?

Comment: @ArtemBilan That makes sense!! im using                                                        @ Inject
    @ Named("producerKafka")
    private MessageChannel kafkaMessageChannel;  Am i doing something wrong in this code or the outbound xml?  And how to make sure if its kafka channel..

Comment: Looks like no, but you should wait some time after the `send()` because the `producerKafka` is a `QueueChannel` therefore *async*. So, your application may stop very early and your messages may even not reach `ProducerConfiguration` at all.

Comment: @ArtemBilan  
i have added Thread.sleep(350); after send ..still im not able to see the messages...as you said i guess its going to wrong channel...how can i check that whether its going to kafkachannel or not..

Comment: I'd make it like `Thread.sleep(10000)` for sure. You can switch on `DEBUG` logic level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and share your logs after send here as an edit in your question.

Comment: @ArtemBilan can you please lemme know how to enable DEBUG logic level  and you mean the application logs rt

Comment: Oh! Sorry for typo. **logging**. I guess you log somehow your application, so there should be some config on the matter: Log4j, Logback, Commons Logging etc.

Comment: @ArtemBilan before that even i have added Onsuccess for listener ,while debugging its not reaching that method..does this mean the message is not reaching kafkachannel?

Comment: Yes, that's why we have tried with you the `ProducerListener` stuff. So, DEBUG logs into the studio!